# How to export html and chart of a single webpage into PDF using AMCharts?

Tags: javascript, pdf, amcharts, html-to-pdf

I have a report as shown in the image below in my browser. I used AMCharts to generate the chart. I can export the page to pdf but it will only export the chart. Can anyone help me to export both the chart and the table to a pdf in one go using AMCharts.
[image: Page with chart generated using AMCharts]

Answer (score 2):

To export a chart with related info from your page using AmChart's export plugin, you need to create a layout and import that information in directly as part of your export process as described [in this AmCharts tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/exporting-pdf-with-multiple-charts-and-related-info/). The export plugin uses PDFmake to export the chart into PDF format, so you can look at [PDFmake's documentation](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/gettingstarted) on what layout options are available to you in the layout object described in the tutorial (note: you can't import the HTML directly - you have to construct your layout object as described in the links).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @xorspark. But the only problem I have is the html table has columns and rows spanning across multiple cells. And I have more complex tables than the one I've shown here in image from which I have to prepare a pdf report with both chart & the table.

Comment: Did you look at pdfmake's documentation and [playground example](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) for tables?  It has row and column span capabilities.

Comment: I looked into the into in and found a work around. I first generated chart in the user's browser, exported the chart object as base64 image, uploaded it to the server via ajax call and then used mPDF to generate pdf with the the chart image on the server and provided user with a link to download the pdf on the browser. Not exactly what I was looking for and kind of lengthy process but will work for me this time. Thnx for ur suggestion. (y)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to that tutorial:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/35076c4d7b6eef7764dacc61f72adadc

But there, they are giving the data of the table by themselves; if you want to iterate through the rows and fetch the data into one array, you can pass this **array** as parameter to layout.content.push({
      "table":{
          "body": **array**}});

This is how I used the function for taking the data from the table and use it in AmCharts Export function:

var header = Array();

```
    $("#chart_2 tr th").each(function(i, v){
        header[i] = $(this).text();
    })

    var data_table = Array();

    $("#chart_2 tr" ).each(function(i, v){
        data_table[i] = Array();
        $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
        data_table[i][ii] = $(this).text();
    }); 
    })
```

Hope it will help you